# Count Until A Specific Value?

Tags: postgresql

Say you've got a table ordered by the date that captures the speed of vehicles with a device in them. And imagine you get 30 updates per day for the speed. It's not always 30 per vehicle. The data will have the vehicle, the timestamp, and the speed.

What I want to do is be able to count how many days have passed since the vehicle last went over 10 mph in order to find inactive vehicles. Is something like that possible in postgresql?

*Or is there a way to get back the row number of the table if it's sorted where the speed goes past 10, and then select the date in that row number to subtract the current date from the date listed?

Comment: Aren't you making this overly complicated? `SELECT now() - timestamp FROM your_table WHERE vehicle = x AND speed > 10 ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1` - any reason why that wouldn't work?

Comment: Is there a way to make this work so it'll give back the value for all the vehicles in the table? it seems like right now it'll only give back one value.

Comment: Yes, but please post your field names and types, then I'll give you a query

Comment: vessel (integer), date (timestamp without time zone, i usually cast this into date), speed (double percision)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (vessel) vessel, now() - date
FROM your_table
WHERE speed > 10
ORDER BY vessel, date DESC
```

This will tell you, for every vehicle, how long ago its speed field was last over 10.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT vessel, now() - max(date) 
WHERE speed > 10
FROM your_table
GROUP BY vessel;
```